# Mutliple bootstrap-selects: z-index issue

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, select, z-index

I am using the [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) plugin for a couple of select. The problem is the dropdown list being displayed for the first select is behind the button that toggles the second select. Check it out (jsfiddle at the end):

[image]

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input id="min-value-input" type="text" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <select class="select-time-unit">
            <option value="m" selected>minutes</option>
            <option value="h">hours</option>
            <option value="d">days</option>
            <option value="w">weeks</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
    <input id="max-value-input" type="text" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <select class="select-time-unit">
            <option value="m" selected>minutes</option>
            <option value="h">hours</option>
            <option value="d">days</option>
            <option value="w">weeks</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

And of course I am enabling the plugin:

```
$(function() {
  $('.select-time-unit').selectpicker();
})
```

The plugin generates a bootstrap dropdown menu. I have tried upping the `z-index` property for the `li` elements of the generated HTML, as well as downing the it for the button itself, but none of this worked.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3oc6baoh/) where you can see for yourselves.

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/3oc6baoh/1/

Comment: lol yeah that works, care to explain why? and why lowering the button's z-index or increasing the li's didn't do it?

Comment: @dabadaba z-indexes work on elements that are positioned and siblings, so in your code, to get the top select to be over the lower select, you need to go up to the level where the top and bottom elements are siblings (in this case the input-group divs) and make sure they are positioned with the top input group having a higher z-index than the lower input group

Comment: @dabadaba  I'll submit it as an answer with an explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Affecting the children won't work, because the stacking order will only go as high as the parent element(s). You just need to set a higher z-index on the parent element of the first `.input-group`. https://jsfiddle.net/3oc6baoh/1/

```js
$(function() {
  $('.select-time-unit').selectpicker();
})
```

```css
.input-group.first {
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group first">
  <input id="min-value-input" type="text" class="form-control">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <select class="select-time-unit">
      <option value="m" selected>minutes</option>
      <option value="h">hours</option>
      <option value="d">days</option>
      <option value="w">weeks</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <input id="max-value-input" type="text" class="form-control">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <select class="select-time-unit">
      <option value="m" selected>minutes</option>
      <option value="h">hours</option>
      <option value="d">days</option>
      <option value="w">weeks</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The top `input-group` having a higher z-index than the bottom one means the "selected" glow around the bottom `input-group` gets chopped off at the top. I'm at a loss on how to fix that while still having the drop down remain visible.

Comment: @AndyJ where are you seeing that? I'm looking at it in chrome and firefox and it looks OK to me.

Comment: It's pretty subtle because the shadow isn't very big, but you can see in this image that the glow extends in to the right hand cell okay, but not in to the cell above. https://imagebin.ca/v/4EYF5P1b1k6U If you focus the top cell you can see the shadow extend down in to the bottom cell.

Comment: Can you reverse the order in the source? https://jsfiddle.net/3oc6baoh/106/

Comment: Good suggestion! I'm using bootstrap 4, and it adds a z-index on hover. But I should be able to override that so no z-indexes are used, then reverse the order using flex and end up with everything playing nicely.

Comment: Awesome! Another feature you might look at is `:focus-within` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within, although it isn't supported in IE or edge at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `z-index` to the parent `<div class="input-group">`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in the plugin as described [here](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/760).

The cleanest fix (and what worked for me) seems to be the following.

```
.input-group .bootstrap-select.form-control {
        z-index: inherit;
}
```